# Angular Binding Not Updating

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm currently learning Angular 2+ and I'm having trouble understanding how bindings work. I've googled this for about half an hour but haven't found the thing I'm missing.

I have a page with a simple button and the text on this button is bound to a property in my TypeScript based on a bool. When I click the button it should flip the bool, but my isTrackingText property doesn't change.

Here's my button in the html:

```
<button ion-button block (click)="startTracking()">{{ isTrackingText }}</button>
```

And here's my bool and the bound text property in my TypeScript

```
isTracking: boolean = false;
isTrackingText: string = (!this.isTracking ? "Start Tracking" : "Stop Tracking");
```

And finally the actual click event:

```
startTracking() {
    console.log("Toggle Tracking!");
    this.isTracking = !this.isTracking;
}
```

Update: Sorry I should have mentioned that I know I can just change it in my button click event, my question is more how I could notify my isTrackingText that it's backing field had changed.

Comment: I've found that I can do it this way in my view:

<button ion-button block (click)="startTracking()">{{ isTracking ? "Disable" : "Enable" }}</button>
  
 But I'm curious now how I'd accomplish the same in the TypeScript code.

Comment: The answers have shown how to do it in TypeScript, but personally, I'd recommend having this logic as part of your template as a) it's purely presentational and b) it means you don't have to keep the values in sync manually.

Comment: @JoeClayn as soon as OP needs to perform the same logic in a 2nd spot in the template or in the component class, it wont be reasonable to keep the calculation in the template. IMO reducing the logic in the template is in most cases the best approach, independent of the complexity of the logic being bounded.

Comment: @Jota.Toledo Agreed, if it's a piece of logic that's re-used in multiple places, that'd be where I'd use a getter or something like that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant "notify" the text property about the backing boolean one being changed. 
What you can do is to either:

1. "Intercept" the setting of the boolean property and trigger the update of the text property.
2. Define the text property as a "calculated" property, which depends exclusively of the boolean one.

Both of this approaches use the [accessors](http://section%20in%20https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html) feature of typescript

The 1st approach would look like this:

```
private _isTracking: boolean;
get isTracking(){return this._isTracking;}
set isTracking(v: boolean){
  this._isTracking = v;
  this.trackingText = v ? ....; // your logic
}
isTrackingText: string;

constructor(){
  this.isTracking = false;
}
```

As you can see, this is kinda verbose.

The 2nd approach is a lot cleaner IMO:

```
isTracking = false;
get trackingText(){
  return this.isTracking ? ....; //your logic;
}
```

Notice that in this approach, as it is, every time that you "access" the `trackingText` member, the value is recalculated. So if the calculation is cpu-intensive, this is not an optimal approach.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers have all shown how to manually sync the values, but another option would be to use a getter instead of a proper field:

```
isTracking: boolean = false;

get isTrackingText(): string {
    return !this.isTracking ? "Start Tracking" : "Stop Tracking";
}
```

This can still be accessed from the template/other code as if it were a field (i.e. you don't need to call it like a function), and the template will re-evaluate it when change detection runs. Obviously this has a little (and I mean very little) overhead compared to updating the value manually, but the convenience factor might make that worth it.

All that said, if you only use this logic in one place, I'd strongly consider just putting it in the template itself, since it's purely presentational. That's just me, though :)

Answer (score 0):

this line:

```
isTrackingText: string = (!this.isTracking ? "Start Tracking" : "Stop Tracking");
```

is just declaring the variable `isTrackingText` and assigning to it the value `(!this.isTracking ? "Start Tracking" : "Stop Tracking")`

So when calling the method `startTracking()` , only the boolean `isTracking` is changed , to update the `isTrackingText` you have to assign its value again so the code will be :

```
startTracking() {
    console.log("Toggle Tracking!");
    this.isTracking = !this.isTracking;
    this.isTrackingText: string = (!this.isTracking ? "Start Tracking" : "Stop Tracking");
}
```

Regards,

Comment: I did realise that was an option but I was more after understanding how I could notify my isTrackingText that it's backing field had changed. Thanks for your answer though!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to update the isTrackingText variable aswell.

```
startTracking() {
    console.log("Toggle Tracking!");
    this.isTracking = !this.isTracking;
    this.isTrackingText = !this.isTracking ? "Start Tracking" : "Stop Tracking";
}
```